# NativeScript slider not showing value

Tags: telerik, nativescript

My xml here

```
<Slider value="2" minValue="1" maxValue="10" />
```

and the print screen, why it doesn't showing min value at beginning and max at ending as well as user sliding value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because the Android slider does not display the min/max values, as can be seen in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html).

You may however create a layout below this to achieve this.

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <Label text="1" />
    <Slider value="2" minValue="1" maxValue="10" />
    <Label text="10" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, i think i will use ListPicker instead

Comment: I got why they design not to show min max value on the slider.
Because we don't actually need it, user can simple slide to begin and end to see them. This make the UI more simply and clean.

Comment: not sure why, in nativescript the slide shrinks all the way, hardly see it ... :/